# Error: module declaration must occur at the start of the translation unit export module occupati

Tags: c++, struct, c++20, c++-modules

I am a beginner to C ++ and I am practicing with structures. Every time I try to compile the program the compiler gives me this error:

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/jacoProject.dir/main.cpp.o 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++   -g -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -std=gnu++2a -MD -MT CMakeFiles/jacoProject.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/jacoProject.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/jacoProject.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/jacopodosio/CLionProjects/jacoProject/main.cpp
In file included from /Users/jacopodosio/CLionProjects/jacoProject/main.cpp:3:
/Users/jacopodosio/CLionProjects/jacoProject/occupati.ixx:1:8: error: module declaration must occur at the start of the translation unit
export module occupati;
```

The code in the files is shown below.
**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "occupati.ixx"
#include "test.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    Employes employeesCompany;
    employeesCompany.initialEmployee = 'f';
}
```

**occupati.ixx**

```
export module employes;

export struct Employes
{
    char initialEmployee {};
    char ultimaLetteraDipendente {};
    int occupatiTotali {};
    int stipendio {};
};
```

Comment: If I put it on the first line it tells me:
`AILED: jacoProject
: && / Library / Developer / CommandLineTools / usr / bin / c ++ -g -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -Wl, -search_paths_first -Wl, -headerpad_max_install_names CMakeProject / main. cpp.o -o jacoProject &&:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "_main", referenced from:
      implicit entry / start for main executable
ld: symbol (s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed`

Comment: @JacopoN: I don't know if MacOS has a compiler that can handle C++20 modules.

Comment: If you are a beginner just learning about structs, I don't think you should be working with modules, which are not even widely supported yet. Just stay with traditional header files for now.

Answer (score 1):

Modules (in *.ixx files) aren't something you `#include` in other source files. Rather, you `import` the components that are `export`ed by those module files.

So, try this for your "main.cpp":

```cpp
#include <iostream>
import employes; // Imports from "occupati.ixx"
#include "test.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    Employes employeesCompany;
    employeesCompany.initialEmployee = 'f';
}
```

Note that the "occupati.ixx" file should be part of the project/build.

---

Note: You have said, in comments, that you use CLion as your IDE/build-system. I don't use this, but [this blog](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4404016836626-Will-CLion-support-C-20-Modules-eventually-) may offer some advice and/or remedies for how to use C++20 Modules in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

You do not `#include` modules. `#include` means to copy-and-paste a file into this one. That's not how C++ modules work.

You `import` modules. Assuming your build is set up to handle C++ modules, you should `import employes;` at the top.

Comment: Thanks, but if I do, it returns me:
fatal error: module 'employes' not found
import employes;
~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~

... but I see the two arrows that if I click it takes me to the connection of occupied.ixx ... I use Clion

Comment: @JacopoN: If your build system doesn't support modules, then there's nothing that can be done about it. So you need to investigate your build system to see if it supports modules.

Comment: yes, it supports modules

Comment: @JacopoN: Does it? What is the nature of its support? Because [Cppreference seems to think that Apple Clang only has "partial" support for modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). Also, modules need to be supported by the build system, not just the compiler. What is the status of your build system's module support?

Comment: partial...at least this shouldn't work?

Comment: @JacopoN: I don't know what you have to do to make your compiler and build system work with modules. I can only tell you how the feature works in C++ as a language. You'll have to consult the documentation for your specific build set up to know how to use them.